# How should I use Arial font while creating word-cloud while using Python3 in Google-Colab?

Tags: python, fonts, word-cloud

I have a data-set of twitter texts which is a mixture of English, Arabic, and Farsi. I wanted to create a word-cloud out of it. Unfortunately, my word-cloud shows empty squares for Arabic and Persian words in the photo. I happened to hear about three ways of tackling this problem:

1. Using different encodings: I tried "UTF-8","UTF-16","UTF-32" and "ISO-8859-1" which didn't fix the problem
2. Using arabic_reshaper: didn't work
3. Using a font which simultaneously supports the three languages like "Arial" font: while trying to change the font to Arial in word-cloud I receive the following error:

**input**

```py
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path = 'arial',stopwords = stopwords, background_color = "white", max_font_size = 50, max_words = 100).generate(reshaped_text)

plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')

plt.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

**output**

```
cannot open resource
```

**This code works well in Anaconda but not in Google-Colab.** The only thing needs to be solved is **what path should I enter for font_path in Google-Colab**

Comment: I think you are not addressing the file correctly. It must be something like this:

`wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf').generate(text)`

Comment: yes I guess I must fix the font_path however the one you mentioned also returned the same error. By the way, I'm using google-colab plat-form.

Comment: This code works well in Anaconda but not in Google-Colab. The only thing needs to be solved is what path should I enter for font_path in Google-Colab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Persian language you have three problem to solve:

1. Persian character don't show correctly. This will solve either with encoding or font which I think you have solved it.
2. Persian character appears but they are separated, in this case you should use `arabic_reshaper`'s `reshape`  function. Keep in mind this don't solve your problem completely and you need step 3.
3. Persian words written left to right, you should solve this problem with `python-bidi` library.

For an example I successfully created word cloud with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

txt = '''I would love to try or hear the sample audio your app can produce. I    do not want to purchase, because I've purchased so many apps that say they do something and do not deliver.  

Can you please add audio samples with text you've converted? I'd love to see the end results.

Thanks!

سلام حال سلام سلام سلام حال شما چطوره است نیست

'''

word_cloud = WordCloud(font_path='arial', stopwords=STOPWORDS, background_color="white", max_font_size=50, max_words=100)
word_cloud = word_cloud.generate_from_text(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(txt)))

plt.imshow(word_cloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes thanks but the main part of my problem still remains which is giving the correct path to font_path arguments. I also tried font_path='/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf' which again returned the same error (couldn't open the source). Please note that my Farsi and Arabic texts are printed correctly but not shown in the word-cloud photo. PS. I'm using google-colab

Comment: I ran your code on my local platform and it worked there. It seems google-colab is the case. Just if you could find the way to give arial font to the font_path argument, I guess it will be done. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded the font to my google-drive and used this code which worked:

`wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/drive/My Drive/ARIAL.TTF',stopwords=stopwords, background_color="white", max_font_size=50, max_words=100).generate(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(all_tweets)))`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to test these specific word cloud libraries for Persian.

- [persian_wordcloud](https://pypi.org/project/persian_wordcloud/)
- [wordcloud-fa](https://pypi.org/project/wordcloud-fa/)

check these out too:

[image]

and

[image]